# Name the following sequence: $30,29,30,35,30,31,30,30,30,28,30...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, time-series

I'm doing a research that is related to the fields of forcasting, time series etc.

I know that a sequence of the type $$\forall n>0: a_n=a_{n+k}$$
where $k$ is constant,
such as
$30,31,29,30,31,29...$ ($k=3$)
is called periodic sequence or a sequence with cyclic behaviour.

How should i call a sequence that performs $$\forall m>0: a_n=a_{n+mk}$$ not necessarily $\forall n>0$, like the one in the headline? ($k=2$, $a_1=30$)

And how should i call a sequence that performs $$ Q>m>0: a_n=a_{n+mk}$$
where $Q\in\mathbb{R}$? (the same properties only with $m$ bounded by a finite number).

Comment: $m$ must be such that $mk \in \mathbb N$, no? And how is this $mk$ different than $k$? Take e.g. $m$ such that $mk = k_1$. Then $a_n = a_{n+k_1}$, which is essentially your periodic sequence. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, $mk\in\mathbb{N}$. Notice that i wrote $\forall m$, so $m$ cab be 1,2,3... But $k$ is constant.